# Laravel .htaccess rewrite and apache2 Location directive

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, apache2

I am trying to restrict access to my Laravel 5.3 app with Apache.

My app is available internally but receives post backs from various external sources. There is a port forward set up with NAT disabled so I can tell internal from external requests.

All URL's should show a 403 except if example.com/api/external/... is the URL. I have the following htaccess (default for Laravel 5.3)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

my vhost config

```
<Directory /var/www/mailer/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location />
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
            allow from 10.64.1.0/24
            allow from 10.64.20.0/24
    </Location>

    <Location /api/external/smsPost>
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

Whenever I access any URL from an external address I still get the 403 even on the allowed location.

```
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
```

I think because it has /index.php even on example.com/api/external/smsPost that it is an issue with htaccess and the location directive not working for this purpose. Is there any way I can achieve what I need with this directive?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a laravel middleware and bind it to your restricted routes?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

     if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath() == "api/external/") 
           return response('You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.', 403);

     // return the $next closure, so other Middlewares can run
     return $next($request);
}
```